# ideas on retrieving data from database struts 2 web app

Tags: java, html, database, struts

I have a struts 2 web app where I have already a log in and register account page. When the user logs in he will be forwarded to a new page where I want to show his name same with register. After registration he will then be forwarded to a page that shows his name. I have no idea how to implement this method from login but I was able to make it in registration page by getting the name from the input text. My problem is: How do I get the data(name) from the database by just using the email in the login page? Another problem is: When I'm in the name page I want a button that when the users clicks the button I want to display all his available info.

[image: registration]

after registration when I click submit the next page will be

[image: after registration]

we can see here that the name is being displayed and when i click search all the data about john will be display in this page as well.

[image: login]

this is the log in page when i log in the next page will be

[image: from login]

but we can see here that the name is not displayed i'm out of idea on how to get data(name) from database just by using the email from the login same and then same sa from registration i want to display all data about john when the button search is clicked

UPDATE:

i was able to get the value of the data now from the database but i was just able to show it on console i cant a way to show it on jsp any ideas this is how it looks
[image]

Comment: ... You're asking how to access a database?

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you mean access?all i want to do is get the name in this example i want to get john by using his email in the log in page.how can i get the name by using email?i have access to database because i have save and log in already and also how to get all other data so i can show it when the button search is clicked?

Comment: @DaveNewton im not that good in java as well but i think its getter and setter sorry im not good in getter and setter so i think you can explain it better than i can

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Any Struts 2 tutorial week discuss how to expose data to a JSP page.

Comment: @DaveNewton i havent seen any that answers my problem. my problem is for example you log in into my app using your email after you log in you will be  directed to a success page in that success page i would like to show your name.how can i do this?answer is getting the name in the database right?so i would like to get your name int he database by using your log in email how can i do this?im out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER ON UPDATE QUESTION:i just put these things on my jsp and it did something good

```
name:    <s:property value="user.getName()"></s:property>
email:   <s:property value="user.getEmail()"></s:property>
address: <s:property value="user.getAddress()"></s:property>
gender:  <s:property value="user.getGender()"></s:property>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very straight forward. You are checking the username and password given by user with the usernames and passwords stored in the database right. The moment you notice that he is a valid user you can do the following:
Create a simple POJO (Plain Old Java Object) class with id,username,password,email,address,gender as object variables, generate getter methods and setter methods with the help of IDE (or) you can write yourself. Once you feel he is a valid user retrieve all these details from the database with a simple "select *" query, create an object of POJO class, set the object variables with values you receive from database query and then pass this POJO object to the view where you will display the username.
Please do check how to display information from database in a webpage using struts2. I hope this helps you.

Comment: i will try to search on how to this in more details but i did understand what you mean the only thing i dont understand and i dont know how to deal with is the POJO thing but i'll be sure to get back on you after i make my move.

Comment: 1 question i'm trying to do the getter and setter found a cool tutorial in java brain. can i still get the value of name even if i dont have an input text in the login i mean the name that im getting is only found in the database not in log in page.so how can i set that value o setter to get the value of name from the database?

Comment: ya even though you don't have an input field name you can get it from the database. With the given email you can retrieve name from database and set it in the POJO.

Comment: look i made something like this user.setName(rs.getString("Member_Name")); and i think its ok because when i sysout it it was ok how can i put it in jsp now?